# How to find modular roots of $x^{22}-2x^{11}-x+2$ (to show it has more than $22$ solutions by CRT).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, roots

**Consider a polynomial $P$ defined by $P(x)=x^{22}-2x^{11}-x+2,$ how to show that there exists an integer $n\geq1$ such that the equation $P(x)\equiv0$ modulo has more than $22$ solutions modulo $n?$**

*My attempt:

1. Since the polynomial is of degree $22$, the equation has at most $22$ solutions modulo any prime numbers.
2. We could easily check that the equation has solutions $x\equiv0$ and $1$ modulo $2,$ $x\equiv 1$ and $-1$ modulo $3,$ and $x\equiv1$ and $2$ modulo $11.$
3. If we could find another $2$ prime numbers $p, q$ such that $P(x)\equiv0$ has $2$ solutions modulo $p$ and $q,$ we could use Chinese reminder theorem to show that $P(x)\equiv0$ modulo $2\cdot3\cdot11\cdot p\cdot q$ has $32$ solutions, and we are done.

But now the main difficulty is that I can't find any $p,q$ such that $P(x)\equiv0$ has $2$ solutions modulo $p$ and $q,$ and this method is primarily by brute force and could be very troublesome. Is there any nicer ways of solving this problem? Many thanks in advance for any hints and solutions.

Comment: Did you check $p=7$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Can't believe I missed $p=7,$ there was something wrong with my calculation, now everything is clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: $P(1)=0, P(2)=2^{12}*3*11*31$ (Pari helped with P(2))

Comment: @ahersh23 Oh I see, it is a nice method to find factors of $P(2)$ , I haven't thought about this before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I removed the CRT tag since the specific question asked has nothing to do with that but rather with finding modular roots of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $x=1$ is always a root.

It is easy to see that for $p=7$, we have three roots, namely
$$
x=1,3,5.
$$
For $p=13$ we even have four roots, namely
$$
x=1,4,4,10.
$$
Here $4$ is a double root.

For a more general approach,
$$
P(x)=p(x)(x^2 - x + 1)(x - 1)
$$
with a monic polynomial $p\in \Bbb Z[x]$ of degree $19$. Now it is much easier to study the factor $x^2-x+1$ modulo $p$. For example, for $p=7$ we have
$$
x^2-x+1=(x+2)(x+4).
$$

Comment: I see! So that any solution to $x^2-x+1$ modulo $p$ is also the solution to the original equation, and now it's much easier to process the calculation. Initially there was something wrong with my calculation, now I understand, and many thanks for your explanation.

Comment: May I also ask how did you get the factor $(x^2-x+1)?$ I tried to factorize $P(x),$ and I got $P(x)=(x-1)((x-1)(1+x^2+x^3+\cdots x^{10})^2-1),$ and then I can't take any factors from $P(x).$

Comment: Well, $P(x)/(x-1)=(x^{21} + \cdots  + x^{12} + x^{11}) -  (x^{10} + \cdots - x^2 - x - 1) -1$ is divisible by $x^2-x+1$.

Comment: I see, I will perform again this calculation. Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: @Chang The ad-hoc methods above ("easy to see", and pulling the factor $\,x^2-x+1\,$ out of a hat like magic) are far from general, so if you seek to learn general method (which do exist)  then you should not accept such an answer (once you mark it as accepted many readers will no longer view it). You can unaccept and hope for more general answers (then later re-accept if none appear).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for pointing out, if so I will temporarily undo the accept and wait for some more general methods:)

Comment: It may be far from being obvious, if you do everything by hand, but in times of CAS, it is the first thing you could try.